# What kind of document is suitable for a book if customer wants changes

Tags: document-classes

I have a situation that I have to write a book from the material that my customer gave and she has not yet decided the layout of the book. What kind of document should I wrote that I can easily change for example

Paper size (A4 vs A5)

Font size and style

Margin sizes

Vertical space between lines

How many letters should the line on maximal length contain, such that the space between letters should be configurable?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no clear answer to this question, because this depends on the material to be shown in the book.

Comment: Oh, well the material is mostly just text. Namely, I will write hand written letters to the book. It contain also a few fractions of the form $\frac{1}{3}$ and temperatures of the form $-15^\circ C$.

Comment: Well, I suggest `scrbook`, the design can be changed afterwards.

Comment: @novicebookwriter, for temperaturs better use `\SI{-15}{\celsius}` with the siunitx package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Well, the question might be a little off-topic, but it was not necessary to downvote it, from my point of view.

Comment: One of the main advantages of LaTeX is that the layout is  mostly in the document class and preamble, and not mixed with the text, so it is a child play change the whole format at any time. But at first I suggest start with the most standard class (book) and use as far possible only standard commands, so you can later move with minimal problems to `scrbook`, `memoir`, `octave`, etc.  At the contrary could be more complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually does not matter very much which document class you use. Most document classes can be adjust to have a different paper size either out of the box or with the help of a package. But even the decision of the document class is at this point not crucial, because you can change it later with little or no effort. Generally, I would use either [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) or [`scrbook`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/). Both offer many possibilities to adjust the layout to your needs.

You can simply start to write the text, since the content does not/should not depend much on the book design. If you have long equations or tables you may have to rearrange them if your customer decides to use a different page size. What I would not do is to start creating figures. Figures depend strongly on the page size and the overall layout. Which font you use, which (text) colors you use etc.

For your last point: you can take a look into the documentation of `memoir` and `scrbook` both have some considerations about the margin sizes, font size and the text width. Also a good resource of information is the [memdesign](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memdesign) document.